# How to arrange copies of arbitrary shape around a triangle in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Basically, how do you do this:

[image: this]

but with precision? I.e. copies of original shape must be rotated and placed to sit precisely at the middles of a triangle’s sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Select the shapes
- Get the **Rotate Tool** and holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> click above, at the virtual triangle center
- Type 120º > Copy
- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +
  <kbd>D</kbd> Win to duplicate with the last transformation

[image: 120º rotation]